# Read Browser's Network Tab to get Response from a certain API using Protractor

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I am using Protractor (Jasmine) for my Automated tests. The scenario I'm faced is to read the Response body from Browser's Network tab and extract certain data from the response body.

Any help available?

Comment: possible, but very difficult. What if you resend the request separately within the session and save the response?

Comment: what kind of request is it by the way? GET/POST/PUT?